# Qt 4.8.5 Mac Handle file dropping on dock icon

Tags: macos, qt

I'm porting some Qt apps to Mac OS. And have some questions because I have no experience in developing apps for Mac OS.

- Where Applications usually save there settings in Mac OS?
- How to handle file dropping on icon in dock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X applications typically save their settings in `~/Library/Preferences/` using an [XML document called a Property List](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html). If you use the [`QCoreApplication::setOrganization(..)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#organizationName-prop) et all methods, just use [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#basic-usage) and your code will remain cross platform and do the right thing.

Handling file dropping on the application icon is a little more involved but [there is already a pretty good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716340/2167797) and also a [Qt Quarterly dealing with this problem](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq18-macfeatures.html). It will basically involve:

1. Setting up the Info.plist in the application bundle to identify what files types are handled by your application.
2. Subclassing QApplication to handle QEvent::FileOpen.