# accept file drop on dock icon

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt C++ for my MacOs (10.11) application but I can't achieve to make it accept the filedrop.

Here's the `Info.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.1">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Created by Qt/QMake</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>QParser</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourcompany.QParser</string>
    <key>NOTE</key>
    <string>This file was generated by Qt/QMake.</string>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
            <array>
                    <dict>
                            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>csv</string>
                                <string>public.comma-separated-values-text</string>
                                <string>comma-separated-values-text</string>
                                <string>txt</string>
                                <string>text</string>
                            </array>
                            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                            <string>Editor</string>
                    </dict>
            </array>
  <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
  <string>NSApplication</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

On my main window I've installed an `eventFilter` but the event is not fired (it does enter the event filter but not for the event `QEvent::FileOpen`).

I've checked theses links but it didn't helped:

- [Registering the File Types Your App Supports (Apple Doc)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html)
- [mac qt app in the dock does not respond to file drop (forum.qt.io)](https://forum.qt.io/topic/30900/solved-mac-qt-app-in-the-dock-does-not-respond-to-file-drop)
- [Dropping Files onto Dock Icon in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489961/dropping-files-onto-dock-icon-in-cocoa)
- [Qt 4.8.5 Mac Handle file dropping on dock icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510278/qt-4-8-5-mac-handle-file-dropping-on-dock-icon)

Here's my `MainWindows.cpp`:

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QFileOpenEvent>

#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setAcceptDrops(true);
    this->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_goButton_clicked()
{
    checkFile();
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject * sender, QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::FileOpen:
    {
        event->accept();

        qDebug() << "Event File Open";
        ui->lineEdit->setText(static_cast<QFileOpenEvent*>(event)->file());
        checkFile();

        break;
    }
    case QEvent::DragEnter:
    {
        event->accept();
        qDebug() << "Event DragEnter";
        break;
    }
    case QEvent::Drop:
    {
        event->accept();

        const QMimeData* mimeData = static_cast<QDropEvent *>(event)->mimeData();
        qDebug() << "Event Drop";
        // If there is one file (not more) we open it
        if (mimeData->urls().length() == 1) {
            QString fileName = mimeData->urls().first().toLocalFile();
            qDebug() << fileName;
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void MainWindow::checkFile()
{
    // Some stuff
}
```

### Where should I dig next to make it works?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to handle the `QEvent::FileOpen` event on `QMainWindow`, but the event is sent to the `QApplication::instance()`, so that's where you want to install your event filter.

From the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileopenevent.html):

> File open events will be sent to the QApplication::instance() when the
>   operating system requests that a file or URL should be opened.